# Extract hyperparameters from a trained Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters

For re-training a model it is useful to know the hyperparameters of the elder model. It could give us a starting point. I have a .h5 keras model where I want to extract some hyperparameters like Batch_size and number of epochs. I have tried `model.summary()` but doesn't give the necessary information and also `model.get_config()`.

Is there any way to extract these hyperparameters of the Keras model?

Comment: Which hyperparameters are you looking to extract?

Comment: are you looking for `model.variables()` ?

Comment: I want to extract batch size & epochs used while training the model. @pavel `model.variables` does not give me the hyperparametere values which I'm looking for. @André

Comment: I think it's impossible to extract those because they are not belonging to the model itself. They belong to the history of the training. The only way to extract those is by saving them into the model file name or to another file.

Comment: As mentioned by @HakanAkgün , you can store the hyperparameters in a `dict` and then using `pickle`, you can serialize this object and store it in a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all hyperparameters of optimizer, please do:
`model.optimizer.get_config()`
If you want to get all hyperparameters of layers, please do:
`model.get_config()`